# Internet Explorer Embedded in Office 2016 Login not honoring compatibility mode greater than IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, ms-office, compatibility, adal

Office 2016 uses an embedded browser control to show the login prompt into Office 365. I believe this uses the ADAL native controls. This is on Windows 10 x64 running the latest everything.

[image: Browser control]

When you enter in a user that is a member of a domain federated to our product it redirects you to one of our pages, which means we're at the mercy of the best compatibility mode this thing can provide.

This control, by default, set's it's compatibility mode to IE 7 and either relies on the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` registry DWORD, or the `X-UA-Compatible` header or meta tag to upgrade to a given mode.

In a proper IE session we can work without issue down to IE 10, but 9 starts causing serious issues. If we set the compatibility header/tag IE will pick it up just fine and honors any value we set. Anything below IE 10 causes the pages to fail miserably, and anything up to edge works just fine (yes, we should write code that is backwards compatible, but this isn't the point of the question).

However, this browser control seems to only honor compatibility up to IE 9, even though 10-edge is specified. In fact, if you attach a debugger to the window you can see the documentMode = 10, but it behaves just as though it were set to IE 9, meaning it throws exceptions as if it were rendering in IE 9 mode. We've tried all the various ways you can set it, but no matter what it behaves like IE 9.

[image: Document Mode]

Here's the thing... I've gotten this working *correctly* in a simulated manner by hosting a browser control in a throw away app and just letting the compatibility flags control it.

I thought that it might be using a fixed emulation flag, but there is no value present in the registry. In fact, adding one doesn't seem to have any impact. Alternatively it could be relying on an old IE DLL, but that too doesn't appear to be the case.

So my question: aside from rewriting the code to be compatible with IE 9, what can I do to force it into IE 10 mode proper, and not whatever this in between mode is?